# Design of redis sets to store list of primary keys from database

Tags: redis

Hey im hoping someone can shed some light on the best approach to achieve the following.

Basically i want to be able to store a list of ids against several types in redis so that i can perform a query using the list of ids.

Ie we have a user type that has actions that were created by them.  i want to be able to get a key from redis like user:X:action_ids == [1, 6, 7, 8] and do a query from postgres like from actions where id in [ids]

Id like the list to be ordered as i will probably only need ten items back a time, so indexing that list of ids is important too.

I have been looking over the docs and have a basic understanding of whats required im just not sure how to combine all elements together to produce the result

Comment: First, make sure what you're trying to do actually requires redis. PostgreSQL has a lot of advanced features itself, including a key-value store a la Redis, so make sure you've fully checked out its capabilities. Second, if you are comfortable with your design choice, I'd recommend hopping on IRC and asking the channel #redis on irc.freenode.net if you don't receive a good answer here.

Comment: @Anorov yeh i was on the channel last night but didnt get an answer, was a bit late though so maybe ill try again

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843030/get-inserted-key-in-redis